# Uploading excel files with different headers to database

Tags: php, sql-server, excel

I have many excel files with orders within from various customers. My problem is the headers in the excel files are at different positions. For example in the first file it's **(OrderID, Date, Unit price, Quantity)** but in the second file it's **(OrderID, Product name, Unit price, Quantity, Date)** How can I map the fields so later it can fetch the data from the proper column of the excel sheets ?

Answer (score 0):

use [phpSpreadSheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to extract the header row and get an array of the remaining rows of the excel content.

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;


$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
$reader->setReadDataOnly(TRUE);

$spreadsheet = $reader->load(strip_tags($your_file));

$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

$highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();

$sheetData = $worksheet->rangeToArray(
    'A2:' . $highestColumn . $highestRow,
    NULL,TRUE,FALSE
);

print_r($sheetData);
```